# Calculus - Implicit Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm reading math notes online [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/RelatedRates.aspx). In the notes there is a problem that differentiates the following equation:

$$    \sec(A) = \frac x {50};$$

...where the angle $A$ is a function of time (ie. $A = A(t)$)

The answer for which is:

$$    \sec(A)\tan(A) A' = \frac{x'}{50};$$

I understand the differentiation of the left side of the equation but I don't understand why the derivative of the right side equates to x' / 50...why isn't the right side differentiated like so:

$$\frac1{50}  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x) = \frac1{50}\cdot1 = \frac1{50}$$

Comment: Are you differentiating with respect to $t$?

Comment: Ok. So because the length $x$ depends on the angle $A$ then it is said that the length $x$ is a function of angle $A$? How would this be written mathematically? How do I differentiate $x/50$ with respect to $A$?

Comment: You write $\frac{dx}{dA}$ to indicate that you differentiate x with respect to A

Comment: What equation can be written that expresses $x$ with respect to $A$?

Comment: But I doubt the problem meant that you differentiate with respect to $A$. I think they are trying to indicate that you differentiate with respect to $t$ because $A$ is a function of $t$ and also $x$ is a function of $t$ (because $A$ is)

Comment: OK. I will have to read more ultimately...My problem is that I'm trying to find the derivative of $\frac{x}{50}$ and can't determine which method to use that would produce the result $\frac{d}{dA}(\frac{x}{50}) = \frac{x'}{50}$.

Comment: But the thing is $x'$ doesn't indicate which variable the derivative is taken with respect to, so you can't just assume that it's $d(x/50)/dA$ because it might be $d(x/50)/dt$. Note that IF it was with respect to $A$, then $x'/50= (dx/dA)/50$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in the context in which the linked page is writing, an expression like $A'$ means $dA/dt$, not $dA/dx$, and $x'$ means $dx/dt$, not $dx/dx$.  If it were $dx/dx$, then it would be $1$.  So
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \sec A = \sec A\tan A\cdot\frac{dA}{dt}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{d}{dt} \frac x{50} = \frac{dx/dt}{50}.
$$

Comment: ok. so...there isn't necessarily a method used to find the derivative of an equation ( a method such as the quotient rule )?

Comment: @P.Avery : I'm not sure I understand your question.  Certainly you can apply the quotient rule to $x/50$.  You get $\dfrac{50(dx/dt)-x(d50)/dt)}{50^2}$ and then $d50/dt$ is $0$, so it's $\dfrac{50(dx/dt)}{50^2} = \dfrac{dx/dt}{50}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Why is [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdt%28x%2F50%29) returning 0?

Comment: @JaneSmith : Presumably Wolfram is treating $x$ as a constant rather than as something that changes as $t$ changes.  Certainly $\dfrac d{dt}\,\dfrac x{50}=0$ if $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @P.Avery : Two other points: (1) the main "rule" used in my answer above is the chain rule; and (2) one finds derivatives of _functions_, not of _equations_. ${}\qquad{}$